# How well does git scale in terms of users/code base size?

Tags: git, version-control, scalability

We are currently using single git repository of ~600MB (that's the size of the .git directory) shared by ~50 active developers.

As our codebase and developer base grow, it seems that this approach will eventually become unsustainable due to increasing code volume (slow git status) and push volume (pushes to master get rejected because someone else has pushed in the meantime).

My question is, how well can the current solution be expected to scale in terms of
(1) volume of code?
(2) number of active developers?

Are there ways of using git (e. g. heavy use of feature branches) or specific technologies that can help git scale without sacrificing a single common history?

Thanks!

Comment: linux is under git. Its number of users is way bigger.

Comment: 600 MB isn't really small. Are you sure you don't have binary in your repository ?

Comment: 600MB?! Do you have binary data in there?

Comment: Large source code repositories can easily exceed 600mb. Don't blame the victim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git was created by [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) explicitely to handle the development for the Linux kernel. This takes into account the number of users contributing the the project as well as the amount of commits created due to that.

If a project of such a size is easily maintainable depends a lot on your workflow. If you only work with a few development branches everybody uses, you will probably end up with multiple merge conflicts. If on the other hand the development is highly separated on (feature) branches, it becomes a lot easier to maintain it as you only need to touch your mainline when the work on such a branch is completed and the work can be merged in. You often have people having special [integrator roles](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow) to focus on exactly that. In case of the Linux kernel, you also have lieutenants collecting (and verifying) commits from the developers and then present it to the [dictator](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Dictator-and-Lieutenants-Workflow) (Linus himself) who then decides what actually goes into the kernel.

Overall though, there is nothing that prevents you from having a huge project within Git. Depending on your situation it might be worth though to split it up if it’s possible (compare with [Android’s OSP](http://source.android.com/index.html) which has a large number of smaller repositories).

Note that a large repository size will not affect your workflow aside from the initial cloning process. Unless you have a ridiculous large working directory (which would affect *any* source control system), it will not affect the normal speed of Git. All commands run locally, and things like `git status` will only need to look at the working directory, the index and the current version, i.e. that will not change if the history is longer. As Git’s data model is a directed acyclic graph, you will have most things you need instantly, regardless of how big your graph is beyond the accessors you use (branch pointers, HEAD etc.).

That being said, 600 MB for your repository is really a lot. I suspect that you have many binary files in it, which might not be the best idea. While Git handles binary files in the same way as text files, the compression Git will not, and the default gzip compression which is applied to every Git object is often not helpful for binary files (like images which are already compressed) as well. So you might want to look into a different solution for your assets if that’s possible.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an issue with a large numbers of users. Proof is that linux is under git.

But the size of your repository let me suspect you don't respect this important rule of many VCS : don't put binary into it. You can't efficiently compute differences in binary files, which makes the repository grow fast.

If the native source format of some big changing elements is binary (often some documentations or media), then you probably should manage that part out of the VCS if the size is a problem.

It should also be noted that git doesn't really define the way you work. If all coders directly push towards the same repository and the same branch, then you have a problem. If some code managers fetch changes and push them to the central repository, then you have no problem. Don't forget that git is a decentralized VCS.

Comment: (1) I think the only binaries in our repo are third-party libraries and icons which basically never change (and all new libraries we reference are added via nu-get instead). Will static binaries still cause a performance problem? (2) Regarding linux, how many users move code to the master branch on a daily basis? I could imagine that even very large open source projects have far lower push rates than a small software shop.